# Loading Multiple JSON to SQL table

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

I have this code working aginst one JSON  file perfect where at first I created the table `TradlensJ`
then I store 2 value in the table originatorId + originatorName  after parsing the JSON file.

How can I do the same for multiple JSON files stored in the specific windows directory?

```
CREATE TABLE TradlensJ
( 
 originatorId  VARCHAR(50),
     originatorName   VARCHAR(50),
)
```

---

```
Declare @JSON varchar(max)

SELECT @JSON = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'D:\TradeLens\20200720020538.json', SINGLE_CLOB) as j
 
insert into [dbo].[TradlensJ] select originatorId,originatorName

FROM OPENJSON (@JSON) WITH(originatorId VARCHAR(50),originatorName VARCHAR(50))
```

Comment: You probably have to loop over your files. Even if you had a function that would concatenate all the contents of *.json in the folder, that concatenated value wouldn't be valid JSON.

Comment: You should create a proper ETL process with a specific tool (for example SSIS if you are on premise or Azure Data Factory v2 if you are on the cloud)